# How to organize a .NET MVC application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, architecture

I am starting to create a complete application in Visual Studio (.NET MVC).  Does it makes sense if I put everything into a single solution and create three separate projects:  Admin (used by staff to manage the app data), Web (public facing web pages), Shared (common data access and other code).  This seems to make sense as later I might add a project for Mobile or an API or ...

If not, how do you structure your solutions/projects in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd have everything in one project and use areas to separate my views and models.

Example,

```
Project
    Areas
        Admin
            Controllers
                AdminController.cs
            Models
                Admin.cs
        Main
            Controllers
                MainController.cs
            Models
                Main.cs
                LoginLogout.cs
                LoginForm.cs
    Views
        Admin
            Shared 
                permissions.cshtml
                admin.cshtml
        Main
            Shared
                loginLogout.cshtml
                loginForm.cshtml
            master.cshtml
            Index.cshtml
```

[Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)

Areas provides a really nice way to section off pieces of your web application, and because it's all in the same project you can have all your sections use the same View Layout (Master Page) to make it all look the same from section to section.

Areas will map to urls like 
    http://somesite/main/index
    http://somesite/admin/manage/index

In that example, you would not put your main section in an area, instead use normal model view controller patterns for the main part of the site, and only introduce an area for admin or other sections.

Comment: I forgot about Areas.  That could work if I run everything from the same site.  Might not work if I need to run the Admin from out Intranet web site.

Comment: To support that scenario I would create two web applications.  One for the main site, and one for the admin section.  In the admin site make it without an area.

In IIS Map the admin site as a sub application on the /admin virtual path.

Then later if you need to move the site, you can just delete the sub app and move the site someplace else.

Comment: Would you put both web apps in the same solution?  Or make them two separate solutions?

Comment: Well, if you've got Visual Studio 2015, it supports Shared Project's now, but in 2013 I would do it all in the same solution.  With 2015 though you can create shared projects to store reusable css, js, views (cshtml), code, etc.  You can referrence the shared projects and it links them into the build.  E.g. a shared project, unlike a class library does not build.  The one referrencing it builds it.  This pulls the code directly into your web apps assembly.  As to css/js etc, it will include them as content when you publish the site.

Comment: There is a bug with shared projects in web app's though, I have a question/answer I posted recently that goes over the work around to use them in web apps.

Comment: I have 2015, just haven't been brave enough to install it yet.  Maybe I should wait for the first service pack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85152/discussion-between-ryios-and-connie-decinko).